# How do I get the current route in an Aurelia html template?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I have an Aurelia application with a page that has two routes pointing at it -- that is, `'create-password'` and `'reset-password'` both point to `reset-password.html`. My `reset-password.js` file injects the Router, so the view-model can access Router.

I want to be able to change items in the page based on which route is used to access the page. How do I get the current route that is displaying the page?

I'm thinking something like `${Router.currentRoute}` should work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best I could come up with, after inspecting the Router object, was to get the current fragment from the history property.
In reset-password.js:

```
isCreateRoute() {    
    return this.Router.history.fragment == '/create-password'
}
```

then in reset-password.html:

```
<div if.bind="isCreateRoute()">Create</div>
<div if.bind="!isCreateRoute()">Reset</div>
```

That's the approach I took to getting dynamic items in the page based on the route.

Comment: This isn't working for me. `var fragment = this.router.history.fragment; console.log(this.router, fragment);` `fragment` is undefined, but I can navigate through `this.router` and get to the fragment values.

Comment: that sounds strange. does console.log(this.router.history.fragment) do anything different?

Comment: It returns `undefined`.